# Get webp image if browser supports it using get_the_post_thumbnail()

Tags: php, wordpress, webp

So I would like to implement webp to a website.
Currently im using `get_the_post_thumbnail()` function to get the post featured image.
Is there a way to get the webp version of the image using this function.

I have tried using the [wp-webp plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-webp/) but it does not work.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the only way I can think of getting around this problem is to check the broswer and serve up a .webp image if the browser supports it by replacing the file extention with .webp

```
$postId = $post->ID;
$patterns = array("/.jpg/", "/.jpeg/", "/.png/");
$thePostThumbUrl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postId, array(768,768));
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera') || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'OPR/') || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') && !strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Edge')) 
    $thePostThumbUrl = preg_replace($patterns, ".webp", $thePostThumbUrl);
```